# What could cause a Spring Cloud Dataflow app to be Running but not Ready on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've set up a little Kubernetes cluster using [`Kubeadm`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) and deployed the SCDF Kubernetes Server on it. When I connect using the Shell and deploy a stream, the apps become `Running`, but the `Ready` column shows `0/1` rather than `1/1`. Kubernetes then continues to restart the apps.

`kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-szv8s            1/1       Running            0          56m
mysql-1wkls            1/1       Running            0          56m
scdf-qw5ix             1/1       Running            0          56m
ticktock-log-0-qqmf3   0/1       Running            4          20m
ticktock-time-df069    0/1       Running            2          20m`

Does SCDF define a [`ReadinessProbe`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/production-pods/#liveness-and-readiness-probes-aka-health-checks) that causes this behavior?

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: Hi, Do you see any info from the logs of the apps? ex: `kubectl logs -f ticktock-log-0-qqmf3`

Comment: The problem with the logs is that the app keeps being restarted and the above command only gives the latest log. I've tried this a bunch of times, but no errors show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the liveness/readyness probes not responding properly.